# Is it allowed to compare coefficients in a discrete model WITHIN the same model?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, binary-data

I am conducting a discrete choice model (specifically, conditional logit). I would like to compare the strength of coefficients (log-odds) between four variables x1, x2, x3, and x4. I have heard repeatedly that such comparisons should not be made for discrete choice models. However, any search I find online says that this can't be done for **different models**. If x1, x2, x3, and x4 are all part of the same model, and they are all scaled identically (0-1), is it okay to compare the coefficients directly to each other?

Is there any source I could cite to support this?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? Do you want to test if $\beta_1 =\beta_2$ (or better: have a confidence interval for $\beta_2 - \beta_1$)?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please include your model in the question?

Comment: @Stefan: What you stated is what I am trying to do intuitively, although in a much more formal way than what I am looking for. What I am trying to do is really put a sentence in the text along the lines of "x1 is larger than x2, ergo the impact of x1 is larger than the impact of x2." (assuming the confidence intervals do not overlap and support such a claim). My understanding is that if I were comparing two coefficients in different discrete choice models, this would not be acceptable. My question is, is it defensible to do it within a single discrete-choice model?